# Angular wildcard redirectTo not working

Tags: angular

I have the following wildcard

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        children: [
             {
                path: 'list/:id',
                component: ListComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'view/:id',
                component: ViewComponent
            },
            {
                path: 'edit/:id',
                component: EditComponent
            },
            {
                path: '**',
                redirectTo: 'list/:id',
                pathMatch: 'full'
            }

        ]
    }
];
```

the :id is a placeholder for the id that I need to get from backend. The wildcard is not working (not redirecting me the list component), giving me the following error

```
EXCEPTION: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot redirect to 'list/:id'. Cannot find ':id'.
Error: Cannot redirect to 'list/:id'. Cannot find ':id'.
```

. Any idea guys? thanks in advance.

Comment: Its giving you error because for your wild card route its not finding value of `:id`. What you can do is for your wild card route you need to define `component` and inside that `component` you can get `:id` from your backend and redirect user to `list/:id` from that component based on your id returned from backend

Comment: yeah.. but how can we fix this issue? Or how can I pass the id into the router

Answer (score 2):

How should the router know to WHICH list you want to navigate if the users enters ANY invalid route?

Should that `:id` be 0, 33 or even 1337? The router can not know!

Only possible way would be to define a fallback router without a parameter or define one:

```
{
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: 'list/77', // put your fallback-id here !!
    pathMatch: 'full'
}
```

better would be to create a site like `404 error`. Show a message like `page not found` and put some navigation options to the user.. maybe an overview of all list or whatever..

Comment: Thought of 404page. But its not applicable. I need to die die redirect to the list page. Sorry whats fallback-id means?

Comment: a DEFINED "list" you want to show if the user navigates to some undefined route.. idk your app, maybe you can show then `list/0` .. maybe there isn't a list to show then.. it's up to you! :)